# ios simulator crashes, real thing doesn't

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I figured this would've been already asked, but most people seem to be having the reverse -- the simulator works, but the iPhone doesn't. My problem is where pretty much all the simulators crash immediately (not to mention the retina simulators are huge beasts even bigger than can fit on my screen), but works fantastic on the phone. Any suggestions?

I'm using cocos2d v3 btw if that helps.

Comment: may be you set distribution code sign that is one possible reason

Comment: what error do you get? when and how exactly does it crash?

Comment: it was actually just a sigABRT error in the simulators but not on e phone. Apparently, I had files blah@2x.png, but I was missing blah.png. Even though in the code, I wrote blah.png, it would continue to work on the real phone. But for the simulators, I had to match it to blah@2x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- You can scale the retina iOS simulators to fit nicely on your screen.

  With the iOS simulator open:
- Got o Window in the tool bar at the top -> Window -> Scale.

Select 75%

This will scale the simulator down to fit on your screen

- Secondly try this:

With the iOS simulator open:

- iOS Simulator - > Reset Content and settings...

That will reset the simulator and remove all user data from it too.